# Как вытянуть значение переменной с функции JS

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему по JS.
Нужно вытянуть переменную "chosenClass" с его значением с функции, чтобы с ней дальше работать.

Заранее спасибо.

----JS----

```
(function(){
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.items > span');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        elements[i].onclick = function(){
            document.getElementById('userResult').innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            var chosenClass = this.childNodes[0].classList[3];
        }
    }
})();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/webEugene29/ot4men92/

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете объявить эту переменную вне функции, т.е. так:

```
var chosenClass = значениеПоУмолчанию;
(function(){...})();
```

либо сделать так: `window.chosenClass =...`, и ваша переменная станет глобальной.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ, но что то все равно не получаеться.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/webEugene29/6q8pwd99/ - закинул полностью код, возможно неправильнов другом месте. Выдает сразу null, а нужно значение с функции.

Comment: Вы понимаете, что пока функция не будет вызвана, никакого "значения из функции" там и быть не может? Это значит, что вместо `null` вам нужно задать значение **по-умолчанию**, которое будет использоваться до того, как функция изменит вашу переменную.

Comment: Если поставить по умолчанию, то скрипт сравнения compare() сразу будет обрабатываться при перезагрузке/загрузке сраницы, а нужно, чтобы обрабатывался только после нажатия на кнопку:

Comment: <button id="play" onclick="compare()">Играть</button>

Comment: То есть логика такая: выбор какого то из трех елементов один, он присваивается переменной "chosenClass " и автоматом вытягивается с самовызывающиеся функции в другую переменную (то есть становиться глобальным). И приклике на кнопку сравнить функция  compare() срабатывает взяв значение этой переменной.